# How to check if the Green candle or Red candle is sitting on 9 ,13 & 55 EMA

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am 2 days old with pine scripting and trying to automate simple strategies to get an Alert when the condition is met . Looked at lot of examples and came up with this . The code doesnt look profession(Pls excuse me)

I want to check if there is a way to check if the 5 minutes candle cross over 8,13,55 ema . Pls let me know if there is a way to do that .

Given my code here

Appreciate any kind of help am

```
//@version=5

    indicator("EMA5 & VWAP Crossover ActualAlert Working", overlay= true)

// Calculate values
    emaValue8 = ta.ema(close,8)
    emaValue21 = ta.ema(close,21)
    vwapValue = ta.vwap(hlc3)
    smaValue200 = ta.sma(close,200)
    emaValue50 = ta.ema(close,50)
//plotting on map   
    plot(smaValue200, title="SMA200",color=color.rgb(238, 247, 122), linewidth=1,style= plot.style_circles)
    plot(emaValue8, title="EMA8",color=color.rgb(71, 197, 178), linewidth=1)
    plot(vwapValue, title="VWAP", color=color.white, linewidth=2)
    plot(emaValue21, title="EMA21", color=color.rgb(204, 71, 142), linewidth=1)
    plot(emaValue50, title="EMA50", color=color.rgb(241, 218, 84), linewidth=1)



    plotshape(series = (ta.crossover(emaValue8,vwapValue)  or (ta.crossover(vwapValue,emaValue21))) , title = "BUY",style=shape.flag, location=location.belowbar, color=#9FE2BF, size=size.small)
    plotshape(series = (ta.crossunder(emaValue8,vwapValue) or ta.crossunder(emaValue21,vwapValue)) , title = "SELL" ,style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color=#f18f0d, size=size.small)





Here are the things i want to do .

My REquirement :

1) I want to check if the Green or REd candle in 5 minutes charts sitting on All the 3 SMAs(8,13,55) @ the given point of time . Right now I am giving as 2 different with AND operator and it is not working .

2) How to figure out the difference between EMA cross over VWAP and EMA touches VWAP . Pls let me know 

3) IS there a way to calculate ORB high and low range for first 15 minutes .
```

Answer (score 0):

To check a crossover, you can use :

```
ta.crossover(source1, source2)
```

See here : [The PineScript Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcrossover)

For your trigger when the candle is over the 3 Emas, do like this :

```
triggeralert = false

if close > emaValue8 and close > emaValuer and close > emaValue50
    triggeralert := true
```

And then define your alert.

Comment: my requirement is When the candle is over all the 3 EMAS(8,21,50) , I want an alert . If I use ta.crossover , I can see if the emas or vwap is crossover .  Conditon is sometimes I see one 5 minut e candle on top of all the 3 EMAs , how do i detect that ?